# Firebase Cloud Functions Not Running

Tags: arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting some unexpected behavior from `Firebase Cloud Functions` where it seems the function below does not run. My expectation is the data in the `/posts` endpoint will be logged to the console. I get no errors on deploying the function.

The function is for a backend-only action that the client/user is not involved in, so a trigger based on database events or `https` wont work for me without setting up another server to call the endpoint.

Is there any reason why the below would not log ?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


 getScheduledPosts = () => {
           admin.database().ref("/posts")
          .orderByKey()
          .once("value")
          .then( (snapshot) => {
              console.log(snapshot);
           })
           .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
          console.log("Posts Ran")
      }

  // Call this function 
  getScheduledPosts();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not defining a Cloud Function at all here.  Because you don't have any Cloud Functions defined, the code you've written will never run.  You have to export one from your index.js, and its definition has to be built using the firebase-functions SDK.  If you're trying to create a [database trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) (definitely read the docs there), it looks something like this:

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/posts/{id}')
    .onWrite(event => {
  // do stuff here
})
```

Don't try to do "one-off" work that should be run when a function is deployed.  That's not how Cloud Functions works.  Functions are intended to be run in response to events that occur in your project.

Comment: I'm was only invoking the function to check if it was running while trying to fix the issue. I have a second function as an exports but thats running either

Comment: To add, the function is for a backend only operation hence I would like a way to invoke it as desired from a backend environment and not on client requests. Is that not possible with cloud functions?

Comment: If you want to invoke a function on-demand at a time of your choosing, use an HTTPS function, and ping the URL for it.  Secure that endpoint as needed.

Comment: Another way to invoke from the backend is to trigger with an onUpdate to a document on Firebase. I set up an 'admin' collection and have an 'update' document. My Cloud Function then triggers onUpdate to that specific document. You can manually change that from the Firebase console or you can invoke that from a totally different admin application that connects to the same database.


`exports.updateItems = functions.database.ref('/update').onUpdate(event => {`